# What is the difference between connecting the subject a the observable at first and at last as both of them are asynchronous?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a code where I am trying to connect a subject to an interval observable:

```
const subject = new Subject();
    
// Connect the subject to the observable
interval(1000).subscribe(subject); //**Line 1**
 
subject.subscribe((value: any) => {
  console.log(`Subscriber A: Value: ${value}`);
});
 
setTimeout(() => {
   subject.subscribe((value: any) => {
       console.log(`Subscriber B: Value: ${value}`);
    });
}, 3000);
```

Output:

```
Subscriber A: Value: 0        
Subscriber A: Value: 1        
Subscriber A: Value: 2        
Subscriber A: Value: 3        
Subscriber B: Value: 3        
Subscriber A: Value: 4        
Subscriber B: Value: 4       
Subscriber A: Value: 5        
Subscriber B: Value: 5
```

This output is what I expected. But now I'm posting another code. I have just changed the position of the line where I connect the subject with observable:

```
const subject = new Subject();
 
subject.subscribe((value: any) => {
   console.log(`Subscriber A: Value: ${value}`);
});
 
setTimeout(() => {
  subject.subscribe((value: any) => {
    console.log(`Subscriber B: Value: ${value}`);
  });
}, 3000);
    
// Connect the subject to the observable
interval(1000).subscribe(subject); //**Line 1**
```

Output:

```
Subscriber A: Value: 0
Subscriber A: Value: 1
Subscriber A: Value: 2
Subscriber B: Value: 2
Subscriber A: Value: 3
Subscriber B: Value: 3
Subscriber A: Value: 4
Subscriber B: Value: 4
Subscriber A: Value: 5
Subscriber B: Value: 5
```

With this output I have some doubts.

1. Why is there a difference in output when we change the position of Line 1?
2. In Output 2, why subscriber B starts from value 2. Shouldn't it start from value 3 like Output 1 as there is a delay of 3 seconds in both the cases? What crucial thing am i missing here.

I tried Code 1 and Code 2 and was expecting the output 1. I have doubts with output 2 and I want to understand what is the root cause behind this type of behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Calling code takes times, in you first case the the `1000`ms timer starts
immediately,

- 0 emited (at ~1000ms)
- 1 emited(at ~2000ms)
- 2 emited (at ~3000ms)
- subscribe B (as ~3010 ms).

It is likely that `Subscriber B` will miss the 3rd value (`2`) by only a few milliesconds.

Where in the 2nd case, it's the `3000`ms that start first, so it will recieve the value

- 0 emited(at ~1010ms)
- 1 emited (at ~2010ms)
- subcribe B (~ 3000ms)
- 2 emited (at ~3010ms) (at this point both logs)

Also keep in minds, timer/setTimouts and others are not expected to run exactly at the given time but only "arround" the given period of time. Sometimes 1000ms can be 1000ms someting, 1005ms etc. Never rely on this duration you pass.